# Wordpress $wpdb->get_results() query

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to run a mysql_fetch_array via Wordpress. I found out the best way to do this is explained here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

Here is my query below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_reminders WHERE reminder LIKE '$today'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    foreach( $result as $results ) {

        echo $result->name;
    }
```

The above is not pulling in any results at all, even though the data does exist. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what `$today` is, but you may be missing a wild character `%` in your `LIKE` clausule?

Comment: $today = date("m/d/Y");

Answer (score 21, accepted):

the problem was the following:

```
echo $result->name;
```

should be:

```
echo $results->name;
```

Comment: Or better, the two variables names in the foreach instruction should be inverted.

Answer (score 14):

The 'foreach' loop and the initial var statement for 'result = $wpdb->...' should be results.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_reminders WHERE reminder LIKE '$today'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    foreach( $results as $result ) {

        echo $result->name;

    }
```

The logic behind this is that you would be gathering all results from the get_results() function and then looping through them as such: (read it out loud - the logic is enforced)

```
foreach ( $ofTheMassiveList as $aSingleResult ) {

        echo $aSingleResult->name;

}
```